# Expired time for acquiring lock pentaho

Tags: locking, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm using pentaho BI (spoon) and I have a problem with it.
At each action (open job/transformation or save for example) it show this window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqmZQ.jpg

now I can't open existing transformation. Does anyone know this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but the problem is still current (version 8.2 CE), and I was unable to find any help (other than the workaround to delete the .lock files, but this only solves it for a few minutes, possibly even less).

I had exactly the same problem, it basically rendered Spoon useless. In my case, the culprit was the antivirus program. I noticed it only because I installed the AV after I used Spoon for some time. I just removed the AV (and installed another one) - no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your repository is having some issue in connecting.

Try checking the **repo. connection** and also check for the **[permission](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Fconcept_managing_content_in_ee.html)** of accessing the repo.

Comment: I don't know if this work, i solved the problem deleting all pentaho folder from my primary user folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and was able to resolve it by deleting the lock file under

```
D:\Pentaho-ce\file-repository\ETL\.meta\metastore\.lock

(local-repository root)\.meta\metastore\.lock
```

Kettle - Spoon version 5.4.0.1-130

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue and was able to resolve it by deleting the lock.

Pentaho tool creates .pentaho directory in the home directory.

inside .pentaho delete .lock from

> .pentaho/metastore/.lock

and also delete .lock file

> /home/pdi-ce-9.1.0.0-324/data-integration

restart your pentaho tool.

hope above solution works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue and was able to resolve it by deleting the lock file under C:\Users\myuser.pentaho\metastore